# Glimpse Debugger with Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, glimpse

Can we attach [Glimpse](http://getglimpse.com/) for the purposes of debugging Sharepoint?

Comment: I have no idea what Glimpse is, but SharePoint "just" uses ASP.NET WebForms as the underlying "rendering" technology. So can Glimpse connect to ASP.NET WebForms?

Answer (score 2):

I did a backport of the glimpse core to 3.5 a while back and made a start on a plugin for SharePoint.

Unfortunately due to having too much work on I didnt get around to finishing the plugin.

I noticed that the Glimpse team have done their own backport now to 3.5 with the latest release so I may pick this project back up again.

It would be good to know what people are looking for in a SharePoint plugin above the obvious.

I can also implement a plugin to work with SharePoint 2013 now that it supports 4.0 runtime.

See [my original blog post on this  at http://leedale.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/glimpse-web-debugger-with-net-3-5-and-sharepoint-2010/](http://leedale.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/glimpse-web-debugger-with-net-3-5-and-sharepoint-2010/)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, Glimpse does not currently work with SharePoint.

Until version 1.0, Glimpse only supports .NET 4.0, and SharePoint is written against .NET 3.5.

You could download the source and make the updates necessary from https://github.com/glimpse/glimpse if you really wanted to.

Comment: Glimpse 1.0 release candidate is now out, and DOES support .NET 3.5. This does not mean we have explicit support for SharePoint, but it would now be much easier for the community to add.